# Change Modal Background to black

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Hello I'm using bootstrap 3 for my modal

I want to change the background color of my modal

Here's the html code

```
<div class="modal fade modal-white" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter code to access form</h5>
        {{--  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>  --}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertThis" role="alert" style="display:none;">
          Invalid code please try again ..
        </div>
        <input name="clients" class="clients form-control" type="password" id="inputCode" placeholder="Code">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="border:none!important;">
        
        <button type="button" onClick="proceedCode();" id="proceedCode" class="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{url('/')}}">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and sample output

[image]

I want to make the background color to all black and only the modal can be seen only. Is there class that I need to add, trying to tweak it using modal-backdrop and modal-white class but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your css file

```
.className {
background-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it's helpful.

```
#exampleModal {
  background-color: black;
}
```